# How do I close a browser window/tab and return control to another tab using Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, browser, tabs

I am using Spring MVC to call a web service.  The intent is to get back a PDF in a separate window/tab in the browser if the call is successful, else if there is an error returned to have the error returned to the original window/tab.  In the jsp code for the html view, I am setting document.forms[0].target = '_blank'; in the submitAction function to create the second browser window/tab to contain the PDF returned by the web service.  This works fine if the web service runs with no errors.  If an error is returned with no PDF, when I return the mav in my controller it creates the action submission page in the second window/tab with the error message showing in that window.  That is not what I want.  If I get an error returned from the service, how can I return the error message to the original window/tab and close the second window/tab that was created by making the target equal to '_blank' in the submitAction function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you have control of the web-service code.

- Instead of a form post to a new tab do an AJAX call.
- If the PDF is created successfully return a URL to the file.
- Open the URL in a new window using script.

If you don't have control of the web-service you can write a proxy service and implement the above mentioned behavior.

Comment: Cahmindu, would you give an example?  I'm not familiar with using ajax. Thank you for your response to my question.